# Find if item with specific property is in JSON array

Tags: json, jq

I have the following JSON array

```json
[
  {
    "login": "foo",
    "id": 111
  },
  {
    "login": "bar",
    "id": 222
  },
  {
    "login": "foobar",
    "id": 333
  }
]
```

How can I leverage the `jq` (preferrably) to check whether the object with `"login": "bar"` is member of this array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`any/1`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#any,any(condition),any(generator;condition)).

```
any(.login == "bar")
```

<sup>[Online demo](https://jqplay.org/s/WFJPJgoiXuo)</sup>